# Cocoa Sparkle framework error on code signature on Mountain Lion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, code-signing, sparkle

I am developing an application for Mac Os X. I have it code signed with a 3rd party Apple developer identity, for independent distribution. In the code, I make some checks for the validity of the signature with CoreFoundation functions as following :

```
SecCodeRef myCode;


status = SecCodeCopySelf(kSecCSDefaultFlags,&myCode);

status = SecCodeCheckValidity(myCode,kSecCSDefaultFlags,NULL);

NSString *result;

switch (status)
{
    case noErr:
        result = @"Code signature is present";
        break;
    case errSecCSUnsigned:
        result = @"Executable is unsigned";
        break;
    case errSecCSSignatureFailed:
        result=@"Signature failed.";
        break;
    default:
        result=@"Error validating signature";
        break;
}

NSAlert *myAlert =[[NSAlert alloc] init];

[myAlert setAlertStyle:NSCriticalAlertStyle];
[myAlert setMessageText:@"Program Beta Error"];
[myAlert setInformativeText:result];

[myAlert runModal];




SecStaticCodeRef fileCode;

status = SecCodeCopyStaticCode(myCode, kSecCSDefaultFlags, &fileCode);

if (status != noErr)
{
    // NSLog(@"Unable to get static code object.");

}

CFDictionaryRef signingInfo = NULL;

status = SecCodeCopySigningInformation(fileCode, kSecCSSigningInformation, &signingInfo);

NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(__bridge NSDictionary *)(signingInfo)];
```

the kSecCSSigningInformation parameter specified allows me to gather information about the signing developer's identity, and Team ID. This works fine in 10.10 Yosemite and 10.9 Mavericks, but fails on 10.8 Mountain Lion. I have checked the situation with RB App Checker Lite and indeed, under Mountain Lion, for the same executable, I get different results shown on the following screenshots :

1)This is the situation in 10.10 and 10.9, and it appears normal, and my code gets the Team ID.

[image: 10.10 screenshot]

2)This is the situation in 10.8 Mountain Lion, RB App Checker Lite fails to validate the executable :

[image: 10.8 Screenshot]

3)If I expand the error, I learn that it is caused by Sparkle :

[image: 10.8 Screenshot expanded]

I have the sparkle Xcode project added to my application's project and it is all working fine under 10.10 and 10.9. On 10.8 too, if I launch the application sparkle does not complain about the signature, but the CoreFoundation functions fail to determine the Team ID, although they report the signature to be present.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

P.s. I have been helped a lot on this problem, and it was recommended to me to remove the 3rd party certificate signing from one of the executables which was Autoupdate.app, which showed in the previous screenshots as being signed with a 3rd party certificate.
Now I sign also Autoupdate.app with the same Developer ID certificate, but the error still remains. As you can see in the following screenshot, if you check the sparkle framework alone with RB App Checker Lite, it says it validates correctly :

[image: 10.8 RB Checker Lite validation of sparkle]

While if I ad to my program the required copy files phase with sparkle framework, I get the very same error as before :

[image: RB App Checker Lite Entire application check everything is signed with Developer ID certificate.]

Again, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Show us your project build settings.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I am preparing detailed screenshots of my build settings. In the meanwhile, I have got this advice from a very good developer : "A hint here is "the signature specifies explicit requirements" in both your app and Sparkle — I think those have been disallowed for some time.". I am trying to verify this.